# Can we classify the solutions of $\ 2n-\sigma(n)=-12\ $ completely?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

This question

[A number-13 phenomenon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585239/a-number-13-phenomenon/3585256#3585256)

contains the equation $$ 2n-\sigma(n)=-12 $$ where $\ \sigma(n)\ $ is the sum of the divisors of $\ n\ $ including $\ n\ $.

There are two families of solutions :

- If $\ p>3\  $ is prime  , then $\ 6p\ $ is a solution
- If $\ p=2^k-13\ $ , $\ k\ $ integer , is prime , then $\ 2^{k-1}\cdot p\ $ is a solution

The only solution upto $\ 10^9\ $ that fits in neither family, is $\ n=54\ $.

> Is the list complete with the two families and the additional solution $\ 54\ $ ?